# Matlab-How to run multiple randi fucntions with for loop without having indicing problems. (nearest neighbor interaction problem)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, random

I have some code where I have a random set of spin up/spin down spinors in a matrix M. I then calculate the total energy for each spin for the neighbors neighbor interactions (M_test). I then sum up the interactions to get the whole energy for the system.
I need to do this for 1000 random M matrices and store it and then graph the energy versus the order (1:1000). When I set up a for loop for i=1:1000 , I get the error "Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side." for M(i) in line 5.

```
clear, clc, close all 
%bounded, where edge interactions arent counted
M = randi([0, 1], 12, 12);
M(M == 0)  = -1;
M(:,12)=0;
M(:,1)=0;
M(1,:)=0;
M(12,:)=0;

for x=2:11
    for y=2:11
   M_test(x,y)=(M(x,y)*M(x+1,y))+(M(x,y)*M(x,y+1))+(M(x,y)*M(x,y-1))+(M(x,y)*M(x-1,y));

end 
end
     %summation       
    M_rows = sum(M_test);
    Energy= sum(M_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I understood well the problem but I think you have to change the matrix size in order to assign the correct index. Here's my solution let me know if it's ok.

```
clear, clc, close all 
%bounded, where edge interactions arent counted
M = randi([0, 1], 1000, 1000);
[n,m] = size(M);

M(M == 0)  = -1;
M(:,m)=0;
M(:,1)=0;
M(1,:)=0;
M(n,:)=0;

for x= 2: n-1
    for y=2: m-1
         M_test(x,y)=(M(x,y)*M(x+1,y))+(M(x,y)*M(x,y+1))+(M(x,y)*M(x,y-1))+ 
         (M(x,y)*M(x-1,y));

    end 
 end
   %summation       
   M_rows = sum(M_test);
   Energy= sum(M_rows)
```